# MySQL find first row base on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose exists a table as follows:

```
id    B     C     D
1     2     3     4
1     2     4     3
2     1     2     4
2     3     1     5
```

For each id, i want to keep the row with maximum B, if B equals, then keep the row with maximum C. So the final result is,

```
id    B     C     D
1     2     4     3
2     3     1     5
```

how to realize it by SQL?

Comment: which version of mysql  you are using ?

Comment: mysql version 5.6

Comment: Must you work with such an old version? Can't you upgrade? Such tasks are much easier solved with MySQL 8.

Comment: Version can't be changed by business team because db management is on enterprise level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum tasks can be solved with `NOT EXISTS`. You only want rows for which not exists a row with the same ID and a greater B or the same B and a higher C.

```
select *
from mytable t1
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.id = t1.id
  and 
  (
    t2.b > t1.b
    or
    (t2.b = t1.b and t2.c > t1.c)
  )
);
```

As of MyQL 8 we can simply rank our rows with `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
select id, b, c, d
from
(
  select id, b, c, d, row_number() over (partition by id order by b desc, c desc) as rn
  from mytable
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a54a906373e0dd00a2fb42c119186dd3

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 5.6 therefore rank function will not work there. Try the below approach

```
select id, B, C, D
FROM
(
  select id, B, C, D,
    @order_id := IF(@current_id = id,
    @order_id + 1, 1) AS order_id,
    @current_id := id
  from Test 
  order by  id asc, B desc, C DESC
) T WHERE order_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thorsten's approaches are fine.  Another method is to use tuples to match the rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.b, t.c) = (select t2.b, t2.c
                    from t t2
                    where t2.id = t.id
                    order by t2.b desc, t2.c desc
                    limit 1
                   );
```